# Changing selectors properties CSS

Tags: css, properties, css-selectors

Is it possible in CSS to change a selector properties with another one?

For example, with `.button:focus` I want to change the background of the body, something like this:

```
body {
  background-image: url(../images/banana.jpg);
  transition: background-image 2s;
}

.button:focus, body {
  background-image: url(../images/apple.jpg)<-- but I just want to change the background of the body, not from the button also
  transition: background-image 2s;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change body background when the focus is on a button? That selector doesn't do that. It applies the property to both  a button with focus and body.

Comment: Not in the way you think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector you will need to either use JS or rethink your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

(Sorry)

CSS has no way of ascending the DOM, this is not how it works - as such any element which is a child of the `body`, such as a button, cannot traverse and style the `body` using a CSS selector.

There are therefore 2 ways you can do this:

1. Use javascript to add/alter the styling of the `body` on the button click
2. Have an absolutely positioned, width/height 100% top left:0 `div` overlayed on the body, then do, e.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qtqs21rx/)

HTML

```
<button>Click me!</button>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
body {
    background:grey;
}
div {
    display:none;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
button {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
button:focus + div {
    display:block;
    z-index:0;
}
```

However, it is likely this will not work in a production environment due to the various dependencies required to make this work, thus making the first solution preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JavaScript to do that, or an efficient CSS cascading of selectors, but it won't work bottom up as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery for it.Because by using Jquery you can change one's property by the event of other element. And it is lot more easier than other methods.